Custom Transformer-Based Chatbot Model Not Generating Valid Responses
I'm currently working on building a custom chatbot using a Transformer-based model for a personal project. Despite trying different hyperparameters, adjusting epochs, and increasing my dataset size, I'm encountering issues where the model fails to generate any valid responses based on my datasets.
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, random_split
import pandas as pd
import math
from transformers import BertTokenizer

# Define the tokenizer
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

# Load the conversational data from a CSV file
def load_conversational_data(file_path):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    print("Loaded data:")
    print(data.head())
    return data['input'].tolist(), data['response'].tolist()

class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, dropout=0.1, max_len=50):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)
        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0).transpose(0, 1)
        self.register_buffer('pe', pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x + self.pe[:x.size(0), :]
        return self.dropout(x)

class MultiHeadAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, dropout=0.1):
        super(MultiHeadAttention, self).__init__()
        assert d_model % num_heads == 0
        self.d_head = d_model // num_heads
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.linear_q = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.linear_k = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.linear_v = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.linear_out = nn.Linear(d_model, d_model)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        
    def forward(self, query, key, value, mask=None):
        batch_size = query.size(0)
        seq_length = query.size(1)
        q = self.linear_q(query)
        k = self.linear_k(key)
        v = self.linear_v(value)
        q = q.view(batch_size, seq_length, self.num_heads, self.d_head).transpose(1, 2)
        k = k.view(batch_size, seq_length, self.num_heads, self.d_head).transpose(1, 2)
        v = v.view(batch_size, seq_length, self.num_heads, self.d_head).transpose(1, 2)
        scores = torch.matmul(q, k.transpose(2, 3)) / math.sqrt(self.d_head)
        
        if mask is not None:
            mask = mask.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1)
            scores = scores.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-inf'))
        
        attn_weights = torch.softmax(scores, dim=-1)
        attn_weights = self.dropout(attn_weights)
        context = torch.matmul(attn_weights, v)
        context = context.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(batch_size, seq_length, self.num_heads * self.d_head)
        output = self.linear_out(context)
        return output

class FeedForward(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(FeedForward, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(d_model, d_ff)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(d_ff, d_model)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = nn.functional.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        return x

class TransformerEncoderLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(TransformerEncoderLayer, self).__init__()
        self.self_attn = MultiHeadAttention(d_model, num_heads, dropout)
        self.ffn = FeedForward(d_model, d_ff, dropout)
        self.norm1 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.norm2 = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, src, src_mask=None):
        src2 = self.norm1(src)
        src2 = self.self_attn(src2, src2, src2, src_mask)
        src = src + self.dropout1(src2)
        
        src2 = self.norm2(src)
        src2 = self.ffn(src2)
        src = src + self.dropout2(src2)
        return src

class TransformerEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_layers, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout=0.1):
        super(TransformerEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList(
            [TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout) for _ in range(num_layers)]
        )
        
    def forward(self, src, src_mask=None):
        output = src
        for layer in self.layers:
            output = layer(output, src_mask)
        return output

class CustomTransformerModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model=128, num_heads=4, num_layers=6, d_ff=256, dropout=0.1):
        super(CustomTransformerModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(d_model, dropout)
        self.transformer_encoder = TransformerEncoder(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)
        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        for p in self.parameters():
            if p.dim() > 1:
                nn.init.xavier_uniform_(p)

    def forward(self, src, src_mask=None):
        x = self.embedding(src)
        x = self.pos_encoder(x)
        x = self.transformer_encoder(x, src_mask)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x

# Custom Dataset class
class ConversationDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, inputs, responses, tokenizer, max_length=50):
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.responses = responses
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inputs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_text = self.inputs[idx]
        response_text = self.responses[idx]
        input_tokens = self.tokenizer.encode(input_text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=self.max_length, truncation=True, padding='max_length')
        response_tokens = self.tokenizer.encode(response_text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=self.max_length, truncation=True, padding='max_length')
        return torch.tensor(input_tokens), torch.tensor(response_tokens)

# Load and preprocess your real-world dataset here
inputs, responses = load_conversational_data('conversations.csv')
dataset = ConversationDataset(inputs, responses, tokenizer)
train_size = int(0.8 * len(dataset))
val_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, val_size])

# Data loaders
batch_size = 14
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Instantiate the model
vocab_size = tokenizer.vocab_size
model = CustomTransformerModel(vocab_size)

# Loss and optimizer
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=tokenizer.pad_token_id)
optimizer = optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

# Function to generate responses
def generate_response(model, tokenizer, input_text, max_length=50):
    model.eval()
    try:
        # Tokenize the input text
        tokens = tokenizer.encode(input_text, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=max_length, truncation=True, padding='max_length')
        input_data = torch.tensor([tokens])
        input_mask = (input_data != tokenizer.pad_token_id).long()
        
        # Log the tokenized input
        print(f"Tokenized input: {tokens}")
        
        with torch.no_grad():
            # Forward pass through the model
            output = model(input_data)
            
            # Check for NaNs in the output
            if torch.sum(torch.isnan(output)) > 0:
                print("Error: Model output contains NaNs.")
                return "I'm sorry, there was an error in generating the response."
            
            # Get the predicted tokens
            output_tokens = torch.argmax(output, dim=-1).squeeze().tolist()
            print(f"Output tokens: {output_tokens}")
            
            # Decode the tokens into a string
            response = tokenizer.decode(output_tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)
            print(f"Generated response: {response}")
            
            if response.strip() == "":
                print("Error: Generated response is empty.")
                return "I'm sorry, I couldn't generate a valid response."
            
            return response
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception during response generation: {str(e)}")
        return "I'm sorry, an unexpected error occurred."


# Training and validation loop
num_epochs = 10
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # Training
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0.0
    for input_data, target in train_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        input_mask = (input_data != tokenizer.pad_token_id).long()
        
        output = model(input_data, input_mask)
        loss = loss_fn(output.view(-1, vocab_size), target.view(-1))
        loss.backward()
        
        optimizer.step()
        
        train_loss += loss.item()
    
    avg_train_loss = train_loss / len(train_loader)
    
    # Validation
    model.eval()
    val_loss = 0.0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for input_data, target in val_loader:
            input_mask = (input_data != tokenizer.pad_token_id).long()
            
            output = model(input_data, input_mask)
            loss = loss_fn(output.view(-1, vocab_size), target.view(-1))
            val_loss += loss.item()
    
    avg_val_loss = val_loss / len(val_loader)
    
    print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1}/{num_epochs}], Train Loss: {avg_train_loss:.4f}, Val Loss: {avg_val_loss:.4f}')
    
    # Log a sample response from the model
    sample_input = "Hello, how are you?"
    sample_response = generate_response(model, tokenizer, sample_input)
    print(f"Sample input: {sample_input}\nSample response: {sample_response}")

# Test the model interactively
while True:
    test_input = input("you: ")
    if test_input.lower() == 'exit':
        break
    response = generate_response(model, tokenizer, test_input)
    print(f"Input: {test_input}\nResponse: {response}")



I've experimented with various hyperparameters such as learning rates, batch sizes, and different numbers of training epochs. My expectation was that these adjustments would help improve the quality of responses generated by my Transformer-based model. However, despite increasing the dataset size and refining these parameters, the model continues to produce either repeated tokens or completely empty responses during training and inference.
here is output:
python ai.py
Loaded data:
                                   input                                      response
0                    Hello, how are you?                          I'm good, thank you!
1              What are you up to today?         Just relaxing at home. How about you?
2  Have you seen any good movies lately?   Yes, I watched a great thriller last night.
3      Can you recommend any good books?  Sure! Have you read 'To Kill a Mockingbird'?
4            Tell me about your hobbies.                  I enjoy painting and hiking.
Epoch [1/10], Train Loss: 9.8999, Val Loss: 8.5966
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045]
Generated response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Epoch [2/10], Train Loss: 6.4885, Val Loss: 8.5841
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045]
Generated response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Epoch [3/10], Train Loss: 5.1883, Val Loss: 10.1303
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012]
Generated response: ..................................................
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: ..................................................
Epoch [4/10], Train Loss: 4.8297, Val Loss: 10.9283
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045]
Generated response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Epoch [5/10], Train Loss: 4.8646, Val Loss: 11.6196
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045]
Generated response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Epoch [6/10], Train Loss: 4.8166, Val Loss: 11.6514
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012]
Generated response: ..................................................
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: ..................................................
Epoch [7/10], Train Loss: 4.7412, Val Loss: 11.3170
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012, 1012]
Generated response: ..................................................
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: ..................................................
Epoch [8/10], Train Loss: 4.7109, Val Loss: 10.7475
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102]
Generated response: 
Error: Generated response is empty.
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: I'm sorry, I couldn't generate a valid response.
Epoch [9/10], Train Loss: 4.6831, Val Loss: 10.1369
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045]
Generated response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Epoch [10/10], Train Loss: 4.6578, Val Loss: 9.8423
Tokenized input: [101, 7592, 1010, 2129, 2024, 2017, 1029, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Output tokens: [1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045, 1045]
Generated response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
Sample input: Hello, how are you?
Sample response: i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i i
you: 

